# How to redirect spam to a different email address (spamassassin/postfix)

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

I have setup postfix and spamassassin on Ubuntu 14.04.

I would like to set it up such that if the score of a message is above 5.0, it goes to one email account on my mailserver. If it's less that 5.0 it continues to the original destination.

I have tried rewrite_header To spam@mydomain.com but this just adds "spam@mydomain.com" to the To address and it doesn't actually go to the spam account.

I can't figure out what I need to do next. From what I have read I think I need either another program to do this, or I have to configure postfix to do this, but I can't find any information on how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: What method did you use to integrate postfix and spamassassin? amavisd? spamd? others?

Comment: I used spamd to integrate them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your spamassasin to a header like *X-Spam-Status: Yes* after that you can redirect mails with:

```
 /^X-Spam-Status: Yes/ REDIRECT spam@mydomain.com
```

in header_checks to a new destination.